# Rewrite Rule to get rid of anchors in urls (i.e. www.asite.com/page.php#a -> www.asite.com/a)

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I am trying to achieve the following:

I have single page website and would like to get rid of the anchors in my urls, so instead of having

> www.mysite.com/index.php#services

id like a redirect to

> www.mysite.com/services

using `htaccess`.

What would the rewrite rule look like and wouldn't it result in duplicate content seen by google? and if so, what do i have to do to prevent that?

Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: and where do you `css` in all this???...tag correctly next time mate, it will help you better!! :)

Answer (score 1):

Anchors are never sent to the server. The server will never know, and therefore can never redirect based on the anchor.

Answer (score 0):

You could have `/services` redirect to `index.php?p=services`

Then if `$_GET['p'] == "services"` have a script scroll to the content.

jQuery does this easily with `scrollto()`

I would recommend `return false` on all your internal links such as `/services` and just scroll to it instead.